# postgresql- calculating difference between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi guys below is my DB schema, I need to be able to generate a query whereby I see for every epic, the difference between the bid_px now and the bid_px 5 minutes ago

```
 epic                       t                   bid_px  ask_px
 MARKET:IX.D.FANG.DAILY.IP  2019-12-17 13:25:19  2985.5 2988.5
 MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP 2019-12-17 13:25:17  7516.3 7520.3
 MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP 2019-12-17 13:25:15  7515.8 7519.8
 MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP 2019-12-17 13:25:15  7516   7520
 MARKET:KB.D.MID250.MAR.IP  2019-12-17 13:25:15 21700  21852
 MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP 2019-12-17 13:25:14  7516   7520
 MARKET:KB.D.MID250.DEC.IP  2019-12-17 13:25:13 21645  21775
 MARKET:KB.D.MID250.DEC.IP  2019-12-17 13:25:11 21645  21776
```

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT bid_px as val2
    from
      ig_markets where t<NOW() order by t desc limit 1
  ) - 
    (SELECT bid_px as val1
    from
      ig_markets WHERE t<NOW()- INTERVAL '3 minutes' order by t desc limit 1
  )  AS  total_count
```

The above shows a result as a total for every epic, I would like it to list the epics and the difference so for example:

```
epic | total_count 
MARKET:IX.D.FANG.DAILY.IP,10
MARKET:KB.D.MID250.DEC.IP,-10
MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP,6
```

Comment: What happened to `MARKET:IX.D.FTSE.MONTH1.IP`? And why the inverted commas around `3 minutes`?

Comment: What do you mean what happened? you asking why is it duped?

Comment: The inverted commas around the 3 minutes is the correct syntax when specifying the time. The desired result is just an example, I edit and list all the epics

Comment: Please define what you mean by "trending either up or down within a given interval".

Comment: so for a given epic the "bid_px" now minus the "bid_pix" <interval> lets say 3 minutes ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understood your issue, but I believe a single subquery could help you, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  t1.epic, t1.bid_px -
  (SELECT t2.bid_px FROM ig_markets t2
   WHERE t2.epic = t1.epic AND
         t2.t < now() - INTERVAL '3 minutes' 
   ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM ig_markets t1
WHERE t1.t < now();
```

**EDIT**: removing duplicates (untested) and selecting the last timestamp - see comments below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.epic) 
  t1.epic, t1.bid_px - 
  (SELECT t2.bid_px 
  FROM ig_markets t2 
  WHERE t2.epic = t1.epic AND t2.t < now() - INTERVAL '3 minutes' 
  ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM ig_markets t1 WHERE t1.t < now()
```

Or using a CTE

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT t,
  t1.epic, t1.bid_px -
  (SELECT t2.bid_px FROM ig_markets t2
   WHERE t2.epic = t1.epic AND
         t2.t < now() - INTERVAL '3 minutes' 
   ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 1) AS diff
FROM ig_markets t1
WHERE t1.t < now() )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (epic) max(t), epic, diff FROM j
GROUP BY epic, diff
ORDER BY epic;
```

Comment: Hi @Jim what's the reason for the epics getting duplicated as I just want to see for every epic the difference between bid_px now and the bid_px 5 minutes ago

Comment: @STEIN does adding a `DISTINCT ON()` helps? e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.epic)
  t1.epic, t1.bid_px -
  (SELECT t2.bid_px FROM ig_markets t2
   WHERE t2.epic = t1.epic AND
         t2.t < now() - INTERVAL '3 minutes' 
   ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM ig_markets t1
WHERE t1.t < now()`